# In Windows 10 it possible to set a unique wallpaper for each display via command line or powershell?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, powershell

In Windows 10 I found the feature to allow setting a unique wallpaper per desktop monitor (control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper), however; I have a need to script this for a large number of computers.  We have a wide variety of sizes and orientations, and we would like to setup resolution-specific wallpapers.

In the Windows 10 applet mentioned above you can choose an image and choose an option for "Set for Monitor x". Ideally we would like to have the same ability via command line or powershell, but so far I've come up empty.